# Column is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

```
CREATE FUNCTION schemaone.get_pg_stat_activity() RETURNS SETOF pg_stat_activity
    LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER
    AS $$ SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity; $$;
    
CREATE VIEW schematwo.pg_stat_activity AS
SELECT 
    get_pg_stat_activity.datid,
    get_pg_stat_activity.datname,
    get_pg_stat_activity.pid,
    get_pg_stat_activity.usesysid,
    get_pg_stat_activity.usename,
    get_pg_stat_activity.application_name,
    get_pg_stat_activity.client_addr,
    get_pg_stat_activity.client_hostname,
    get_pg_stat_activity.client_port,
    get_pg_stat_activity.backend_start,
    get_pg_stat_activity.xact_start,
    get_pg_stat_activity.query_start,
    get_pg_stat_activity.state_change,
    get_pg_stat_activity.wait_event_type,
    get_pg_stat_activity.wait_event,
    get_pg_stat_activity.state,
    get_pg_stat_activity.backend_xid,
    get_pg_stat_activity.backend_xmin,
    get_pg_stat_activity.query,
    get_pg_stat_activity.backend_type
FROM schemaone.get_pg_stat_activity() get_pg_stat_activity(datid, datname, pid, usesysid, usename, application_name, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, backend_start, xact_start, query_start, state_change, wait_event_type, wait_event, state, backend_xid, backend_xmin, query, backend_type);
```

I have these queries here; I get the following error when I try using pg_restore.

> 10:33:56 1251111 ERROR  string_utils.c:650
> pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  column reference "query" is ambiguous
> 10:33:56 1251111 ERROR  string_utils.c:650
> LINE 20:     get_pg_stat_activity.query,

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! What does this do - `get_pg_stat_activity(datid, datname, pid, usesysid, usename, application_name, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, backend_start, xact_start, query_start, state_change, wait_event_type, wait_event, state, backend_xid, backend_xmin, query, backend_type);`? I think it's redundant and may even be the source of your error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to re-use PostgreSQL version 10-12 definition of [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) in your alias, while being on [version 14+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) so the alias list doesn't match the names and amount of output columns, leaving you with 2 stray, unaliased columns causing the conflict. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TIBkQajj):

| ordinal_position | source_column | your_alias | is_equal | name_shifted_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | datid | datid | t | 0 |
| 2 | datname | datname | t | 0 |
| 3 | pid | pid | t | 0 |
| 4 | **leader_pid** | **usesysid** | **f** | 1 |
| 5 | usesysid | usename | f | 1 |
| 6 | usename | application_name | f | 1 |
| 7 | application_name | client_addr | f | 1 |
| 8 | client_addr | client_hostname | f | 1 |
| 9 | client_hostname | client_port | f | 1 |
| 10 | client_port | backend_start | f | 1 |
| 11 | backend_start | xact_start | f | 1 |
| 12 | xact_start | query_start | f | 1 |
| 13 | query_start | state_change | f | 1 |
| 14 | state_change | wait_event_type | f | 1 |
| 15 | wait_event_type | wait_event | f | 1 |
| 16 | wait_event | state | f | 1 |
| 17 | state | backend_xid | f | 1 |
| 18 | backend_xid | backend_xmin | f | 1 |
| 19 | **backend_xmin** | **query** | f | 2 |
| 20 | **query_id** | **backend_type** | f | 2 |
| 21 | **query** | **query (2)** | f | 0 |
| 22 | **backend_type** | **backend_type** (2) | f | 0 |

4th column of `pg_stat_activity` is `leader_pid` and by ommitting it in your list, you're still selecting it but renaming as `usesysid` and shifting all the column names that follow, one up/to the left. 20th column is `query_id` that you also skipped, so at the end, you're still selecting everything that comes out of `pg_stat_activity` through your `schemaone.get_pg_stat_activity()` function, but renaming columns 4-20, then leaving the last two unaliased, which happen to be `query` and `backend_type`.

So the last 4 columns that result from this:

```sql
schemaone.get_pg_stat_activity() get_pg_stat_activity(datid, datname, pid, usesysid, usename, application_name, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, backend_start, xact_start, query_start, state_change, wait_event_type, wait_event, state, backend_xid, backend_xmin, query, backend_type);
```

are `query`, `backend_type`, `query`, `backend_type`, causing the conflict.

You need to make your aliases match:

```sql
CREATE VIEW schematwo.pg_stat_activity2 AS
SELECT *
FROM schemaone.get_pg_stat_activity() get_pg_stat_activity(datid, datname, pid, leader_pid, usesysid, usename, application_name, client_addr, client_hostname, client_port, backend_start, xact_start, query_start, state_change, wait_event_type, wait_event, state, backend_xid, backend_xmin, query_id, query, backend_type);
```

or remove that list entirely

```sql
CREATE VIEW schematwo.pg_stat_activity AS
SELECT *
FROM schemaone.get_pg_stat_activity() AS get_pg_stat_activity;
```