# create view for all tables from multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, azure, view, psql, dblink

I have seveval databases in a postgresql db server

each database has its own username/password, and only access by nominate schema (in fact, the schema is same name of the username)

I'd like to create a all_tables view, so i can do query later.

I did some research on `dblink` extension, but still can't make it work.

```
SELECT dblink_connect('source_db_1', 'postgres://db_1:password@psqlserver.postgres.database.azure.com/db_1?sslmode=require');
CREATE SERVER source_db_1 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER dblink_fdw OPTIONS (hostaddr 'psqlserver.postgres.database.azure.com', dbname 'db_1');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user SERVER source_db_1 OPTIONS (user 'db_1', password 'password');

SELECT dblink_connect('source_db_2', 'postgres://db_2:password@psqlserver.postgres.database.azure.com/db_2?sslmode=require');
CREATE SERVER source_db_2 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER dblink_fdw OPTIONS (hostaddr 'psqlserver.postgres.database.azure.com', dbname 'db_2');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user SERVER source_db_2 OPTIONS (user 'db_2', password 'password');

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tables_in_db_1 AS
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_1';

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tables_in_db_2 AS
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_2';

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tables_in_db_3 AS
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db_3';


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tables AS
SELECT * FROM all_tables_in_db_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM all_tables_in_db_2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM all_tables_in_db_3;
```

all commands run fine, but when query in `all_tables`, there is no any tables

Comment: 1) Pretty sure `SELECT dblink_connect()` is in wrong order and is incorrect. See [dblink_connect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html) for proper usage. 2) I don't see that your views are actually connecting to the other databases, just to the local one and filtering by table_schema. 3) I don't see you giving the user permissions on the foreign server.

Answer (score 0):

1. `dblink_fdw` could do, but it's recommended that you use the native [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) instead.
2. You don't need to both `dblink_connect` and set up the `server` and `user mapping`. You use the former to manage connections to call `dblink_execute`, the latter to set up the foreign data wrapper and subsequently, a [`foreign table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html) that uses them.
3. What you did doesn't automatically add visibility of everything in the other databases to your `information_schema`. You can either run queries through [`dblink_exec`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-exec.html) and work with their output, or set up the `foreign table` or [`import foreign schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html) for many tables at once. The second option most resembles what you expected it to do.

Here's an example showing how to set up an `information_schema.tables` but for multiple databases. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aAFCZypA):

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER foreign_server
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (hostaddr 'psqlserver.postgres.database.azure.com', 
           dbname 'db_2');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user
  SERVER foreign_server
  OPTIONS (user 'db_2', 
           password 'password');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE db_2_information_schema_tables
  (table_catalog name, table_schema name, table_name name, table_type character varying, self_referencing_column_name name, reference_generation character varying, user_defined_type_catalog name, user_defined_type_schema name, user_defined_type_name name, is_insertable_into character varying, is_typed character varying, commit_action character varying)
  SERVER foreign_server
  OPTIONS (schema_name 'information_schema', 
           table_name 'tables');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_pg_all_tables AS
SELECT 'local' as dbname, * FROM information_schema.tables
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db_2'           , * FROM db_2_information_schema_tables;
```

Unfortunately, `create foreign table` doesn't accept `(like another_table)` syntax so you need to list the column names and types on your own.

In different versions of PostgreSQL Built-in tables and views can have different column names in different order, which you need to bear in mind whenever you link them as `foreign table`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378569/column-is-ambiguous/77379108#77379108) is an example of view definition re-use going wrong.

Comment: regarding `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`, that looks too complex to implement. In db_1, db_2, db_3, etc, there are hundred tables, with different table structure.

Comment: You only need to link one `information_schema.tables` from each database. That's a system view that lists all of them db-wide. As long as the version of the db matches, the structure of that system view will match as well. That's of course assuming your goal is to have a *list* of all tables seen in all your databases, as opposed to some sort of concatenation of their contents.